# Vaadin grid 'Comparison method violates its general contract!' error

Tags: java, vaadin7

I am using Vaadin 7.7.3 with a grid that represents a table with a list of users. I have several columns: name, family name, email, user id, ....

In some cases, I perform a sort executing this code:

```
sort(Sort.by(LASTNAME).then(FIRSTNAME).then(EMAIL));
```

In my testing machine, works fine. But when I test it in production server, launches a `Comparison method violates its general contract!`. I understand what this error means, at least, it is clear to me if I am sorting a list of elements.

Extra information:

- These three fields are defined as **strings**.
- If I run the code in my local machine, it works correctly and the exception is never thrown. But in production, each time I sort this grid, the exception is launched.
- Database collations are the same in production and local machine.
- Same data in both databases (using mysqldump I have copied data from production to local machine, and still works fine).

What can cause that issue when comparing strings?

If the data in both application is the same, can be caused this exception by an external source? Something like database configuration, collations, JVM version, ...

Comment: Are the versions of the JDKs different between test and production? JDK 7 introduced a [change to the sorting algorithm](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6804124) used by Arrays.sort and Collections.sort. The old implementation silently ignored errors but the new one may throw an exception. This wouldn't explain the cause of the error, but might explain why it is happening on one environment and not the other

Comment: Yes, are different. One is Openjdk v1.8.0.111 where errors are shown, and in Oracle JDK 1.7.0.79_b15 errors are not shown. Maybe your are right, I need to test it in my local using same version of java.

Comment: Seems that only by changing from Open JDK 8 to Oracle JDK 8, the exception disappears. Your assumption is correct and it is related to JVM. But Oracle JDK 8 does not shown the error and the sort is done correctly. Maybe is an Open JDK 8 issue.